# How to remove border from Fancybox 2?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I need a bit of help over there.
Here I need to remove white border from fancybox iframe http://squaretwo.ru/pashokk .

You can call fancyBox by clicking the red button.
I've read previous articles but wasn't able to fix the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: try to change css padding to 0 - for that block http://squaretwo.ru/pashokk/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove that by adding this to your stylesheet.

The structure of your iFrame is such,

```
<body style="overflow-x: hidden; ">
    <div style="max-width:550px; border: solid 15px #cc0033;" border="1">
       .
       .
       .
    </div>
</body>
```

So you can remove the border like so,

```
body div:first-child {
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

But, this will affect any border properties that you have given to your `#header`, since that is a `div:first-child` as well.

so do a `!important` for your `div#header` border properties (IF NEEDED).

**EDIT**

Since you want to get rid of the fancybox background.

You'll need to add this,

```
.fancybox-skin {
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

this is a default class generated by the plugin.

Also,

add the following

```
html{
  background: white;
}
```

If you want the background only inside the red border then don't add the above `html` css, add the following.

```
body div:first-child {
     background: white !important;
}
```

Comment: I think that my question was a bit incorrect. I need to keep the red border and remove Fancybox's white frame. After adding your code, only red border disappeared. http://jsfiddle.net/fU54x/ I think this is the solution of my problem but for me it doesnt work with iframe.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

when calling the fancy box script you can also set padding:0 as an option.
In your javascript :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
         padding: 0
    });
});
```

And there you go no padding.